# Customize reference style for enumeration items

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

How can I achieve that the reference to the second item in the following enumeration is just `(a)` and not `(1a)`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document} 
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
 \item\label{1} ABCD
 \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
   \item\label{a} xyz
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Now refer to \eqref{a}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One might argue about the usefulness of using `(a)` when you refer to a subitem `1a` -- unless it's unique and clear.  I would use `\ref` and not `\eqref` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under [`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart) the reference prefix - denote by `\p@`-style macros - for each level of an `enumerate` is set to be hierarchical, thereby inheriting that of the previous level. You can remove this prefix in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{}% Remove prefix for second-level enumerate item
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{enumerate}
 \item\label{1} ABCD
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item\label{a} xyz
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Now refer to (\ref{a}).

\end{document}
```

Note that there is no formatting of the labels required, as the default matches your anticipated output.

Comment: A nice solution to -- I should look into `p@enumii` ;-) (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty method: `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` instead of `enumerate` and say `label={(\alph*)}]` or `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]`. This uses the correct labelling.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document} 
\begin{enumerate}[(1),leftmargin=*]
 \item\label{1} ABCD
 \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
   \item\label{a} xyz
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Now refer to \ref{a}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it dirty?

Comment: @lpdbw: It drops `enumerate` and uses another (easier to use package?), i.e. `enumitem`

Comment: I see, you would in general say `enumitem` is "better"?

Comment: @lpdbw: It's more flexible, more up-to-date, in my point of view. But it can't be used fully with `beamer`, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer careful choice of words in your answer to the comment:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I remember you are somehow involved in `enumerate` package, but most probably you will deny this ;-)